# c# print to matrix printer via serial port (bluetooth adapter)

Tags: c#, printing, com-port

I need to write a code to print anything in c# and wince mobile (or desktop app) to matrix printer via serial port (bluetooth adapter).
I connect printer (epson lx) to my pc via bluetooth to COM5, 9600 bps, ... and trying to print with folowing code, and it work (print) something else.

Somebody help me with code for printing 'Hello World'?

My test code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.IO;

SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();

ComPort.PortName = "COM5";

ComPort.Open();

ComPort.Write("Hello World");

ComPort.Close();
```

Comment: Just to make sure - you are sending the string "Hello World" to the printer, but it prints something else? Then what is being printed?

Comment: Have you verified that it is corrent to just send a string to your serial port? For other printer makes you usualy need either use a windows printer driver, or if you send a plain string it must be formatted in a make-specific print-language that defines things like font/size etc.

Comment: it prints string in format: ascii(220)...ascii(255) instead Hello World.
I have no printer driver installed

Comment: Printer Epson is connected: Serial port (printer) -> Serial port (pc-bluetooth-bluetooth adapter)

Comment: It looks lioke you send Unicode string (default in .NET) but printer needs ASCII.

Comment: Yes, I send Unicode not ASCII
Will I finish my work (print exact string) by ASCII string?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I test this but it give same result like Unicode string

string value = "Hello World";

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);

ComPort.Write(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length);

Comment: OK, check your printer settings first so they fits your COM port settings. Here you can find description: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/48456/Epson-Lx-300.html?page=86#manual

Comment: There is ESC/p (Epson printer control language) that you can use to set things like font/size and also charater tables. The latter might help adressing your issue. See https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf or https://www.manualslib.com/manual/48456/Epson-Lx-300.html?page=88#manual

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thank you, I set printer baud rate to 9600 (default is 19200) and my initially test code work fine. It works with/without Ascii encoding.
Now, I know how to code with ESC/P control language...

Answer (score 1):

I set printer baud rate to 9600 (default is 19200) and my initially test code work fine. It works with/without Ascii encoding.